# XSLT: Ignore and skip data for an element and its entire branch of child elements if attribute is set false?

Tags: xslt, xpath, attributes

XSLT: Ignore and skip data for an element and its entire branch of child elements if an attribute is set false?

I have an XML document which has `Document > Sections > Sub Sections > Items > Sub Items > Super Subs` etc and so on.

Now one common 'Boolean' Attribute or Attribute Set I am setting as common for all Elements at every level is "V" for visibility or visible i.e. Allowing me to hide/ skip or make invisible entire section of the document.

Since it is Boolean it can hold 1 or 0 i.e. True/ False.

I'd like to be able to `IGNORE` and `SKIP` processing and output of *any* element and its entire branch of child elements if I need it hidden/ unprocessed and ignored by simply changing one Boolean attribute as a flag.

What would be a good, clean, efficient way of going about this?

Would there be a common Xpath expression that would allow this to apply globally to entire set of elements at all levels across the XML document?

I welcome all suggestions and alternative ways of implementing and going about this.

e.g. XML:

```
<Document> 
 <Section v="1">Data 
<SubSection v="1">SS1..</SubSection>
<SubSection v="0">SS2..</SubSection>
 </Section> 
 <Section v="0"></Section> 
 <Section v="1"></Section>
</Document>
```

Comment: Any chance you can post an example of your input XML and the output you would expect from it?

Comment: The XML could be of any type. 
I am designing several XML Schemas and I want this to be a common feature in all of them. 
To be able to hide/ignore a "Chunk" or "Branch" of Data as and when needed without destroying or removing the data.

Answer (score 2):

If you are processing your document with a normal `<xsl:appy-templates/>` recursive walk over the input tree then you just need

```
<xsl:template match="*[@V='0']" priority="10"/>
```

which says to output nothing and don't process the children of elements with `V="0"`